# Generating a collision immune obfuscating slug manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, obfuscation

I am trying to generate a small hash manually to obfuscate my webapp IDs

(I have explained why I am doing this manually instead of using a real hash such as SHA, MDA or even an encoded hash such as hashid in this thread: [hashids vs pure random hash in id obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459345/hashids-vs-pure-random-hash-in-id-obfuscation) )

This hash is purely random: I pick some digits from an alphanumerical string :

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
```

Here is my code :

model.rb

```
class Model< ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_hashid
  validates :hashed_id, uniqueness: true

  private

  def set_hashid
    chain = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
    numberdigits = 4

    until @hash.present? && !Model.exists?(hashed_id: @hash)
      @hash = ""
      numberdigits.times do
        @hash << chain[rand(0..chain.size-1)]
      end
    end

    self.hashed_id = @hash
  end

end
```

It works perfectly well. A hash made of 4 digits from the `chain` string is created. It gives 36^4= 1.679.616 possibilities

It is plentyful for my model (should reach 1.000.000 eventually)

The hash passes when a search on the model in field `hashed_id` return false.

Though two problems :

**1st :** My database is empty so it's pretty fast. But what will be the search time of a 4 digit hash in an indexed column when this column has 1 millions records ? Is there a way to anticipate this (appart from finding a similar dummy table which I may struggle to)

**2st :** I enforce a validation with `uniqueness` so I guess a search for this hash is made inside my `set_hashid` but is done also when enforcing the validation which is redundant. Though I am keen on keeping the validation in case a similar hash passes the test with another user at the same moment(very very very unlikely but who knows). Is there a way to do differently so no extra search is done and validation is kept?

Comment: Ruby already has SecureRandom which generates various hashes and UUIDs. I think you're overblowing the chance of collision issue as premature optimisation. If uuid v4 works for the likes of Facebook it will work for you. If you're using postgres you can use the UUID extension to define UUID columns in which case the DB handles the generation which saves the round trips between the app and DB.

Comment: Thank @max UUIDs are way too long for me because it will show in path. Well it is a valid option, but try to do something pretty. Random_bytes actually seem to do the job, but it only replicates my small function `set_hashid` .. Will rethink this but a check against database seem inevitable if I want it this way. I will check if something like Random_bytes exists with PG

Comment: You can use something like `SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT chr((97 + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) 
FROM generate_series(1,15)), '');` to generate a random string in Postgres or use a user defined function. You can use this to set the column default in Postgres in which case no rails validation/logic is needed.

Comment: that sounds just great. I guess PG uniqueness will be enforced. I will try this tks

Comment: Actually I was a bit wrong. You cant use a function for a default. You have define a trigger which sets it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'secure_random'
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :set_hashid!, unless: -> { self.hash_id }
  def set_hashid!
    begin
      self.hashed_id = SecureRandom.hex(2)
    end while self.class.exists?(hashed_id: self.hashed_id)
  end
end
```

`begin ... while condtion` runs the block at least once and will run `self.hashed_id = SecureRandom.hex(2)` repeatedly in the chance of collision.

`2` is the length in bits used by `SecureRandom.hex` (it gives a length of 4).

A uniqueness validation will not provide any extra value since it just checks if a record with that value exists and you're already checking that in the callback. Application level validations are also prone to the very race conditions you would be trying to counter.

Instead this should be enforced by a unique index in the database.

You could also create a Postgres function and use it generate a random string and use it in a trigger to set the value. But I would start with this and look into this when the performance actually is a problem.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know the `uniqueness` could trigger race conditions. I thought it was sort of locking the database when doing the check. I will then stick to your answer. There are very little chances a collision appear and be  so simultaneous than a race encurs on top.